# Java: removing elements from a collection

Tags: java, collections, addition

I have a collection, and I want to implement the add() method, such that only positive integers can be added to the collection.  The collection can hold 4 values, and I have used the code below to initialize every value as "-1".

```
  public class Bag implements Collection {


private int[] elements;

public Bag() {
    elements = new int[Runner.SIZE_OF_COLLECTION];
    for (int i = 0; i < Runner.SIZE_OF_COLLECTION; i++) {
        elements[i] = -1;
    }
}
```

So far in the method add() below, I have this loop iterating through each element in the collection, and replacing each element that's less than 0 with the positive integer that I want to add ("toAdd").

The problem is, I only want to add the positive integer "toAdd" once, and without a break in the loop, the method replaces EVERY element "-1" in the collection with the positive integer.  With the break in the loop, the method fails to add the positive integer at all.  Any ideas on how I can get the method to add the positive integer to the collection only once?

```
public void add(int toAdd) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Runner.SIZE_OF_COLLECTION; i++) {
        if (elements[i] <= 0 && toAdd>0) {
            elements[i] = toAdd;
            }
                        break;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect elements array is empty. Try printing out the size and content inside add method.

Comment: the title is somewhat misleading... I believe that you might have to spend a little bit more time in the design process for this particular problem. Also, what's Runner?

Comment: Runner is the class that sets the size of the collection, and yeah, I in the title I meant "adding" methods to a collection, not "removing"

Answer (score 1):

Move the break into the if statement.

Comment: already tried that, and it still didn't let me add a positive integer :(  thanks though!

Comment: What is the result? All -1? Try printing out the value of Runner.SIZE_OF_COLLECTION inside add()

Comment: You'll have to show how toAdd is being called and how you are printing out the collection in your test because I don't think the error is in the toAdd function with the break placed in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ArrayList instead of an int array. With an ArrayList, you could get the index of the first occurence of -1 and use the [**set**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29) method to add your new value at that index.

Answer (score 0):

This replaces the first value from `elements`, which is equal or less than 0, with value from `toAdd` argument.

```
public void add(int toAdd) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Runner.SIZE_OF_COLLECTION; i++) {
        if (elements[i] <= 0 && toAdd>0) {
            elements[i] = toAdd;
            break;
        }             
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The add method for the interface Collection takes an Object (or a generic type, which you have not specified).  If you are trying to override / implement the collection interface method with your add method, then the method signature is incorrect, and it will never be called.

Your class needs to look like:

```
public class Bag implement Collection<Integer>
{
  // ... other necessary methods

  public boolean add(Integer i)
  {
    // your method...
  } 
}
```

And probably easier than your implementation would be to do:

```
public class Bag extends java.util.ArrayList<Integer>
{
  @Override
  public boolean add(Integer i)
  {
    if ((i != null) && (i > 0)) super.add(e);
  }
}
```

You probably need to override the other add methods as well, although truthfully, it would be better to encapsulate the ArrayList instead of extending it.